# SQL table column name with comma should be saved exactly in same manner in csv file header

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am having SQL table column name as 10,000 and I want it to be saved as 10,000 in csv file. But the problem is when I save the data in csv file 10,000 is saved as 10 in a separate cell and 000 in a separate cell.

[image: Column name which I'm getting]

I am calling an SP to get the data and storing it in a data table where column name is coming as 10,000. But i am facing the problem when i am save it in csv file using memory stream in c#.

[image: Expected column name]

Comment: And how you create the csv? And please no picture of that.

Comment: Besides for looking at a csv don't use Excel(i assume its Excel) . Its just text and Excel thinks that it needs to apply magic that does not help.

Comment: @Ralf - I am not able to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: It is as easy formulated as i'm able to. Maybe someone else can rephrase.

Comment: When u save it as CSV put it between quotes like this "10,000" and the comma will not be interpreted as a new cell.

Comment: Please check [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How do you create your csv? What tool do you use? Please provide code, sample data.

Comment: You are uploaded a csv which each column is separated by a comma.  The number also have a comma 10,000.  So the column must have a double quote so import know the difference between a comma in a number and the comma separating the columns.

Comment: I don't think a csv file supports column names with a "," in them? I would thus alias the SQL column from 10,000 to 10000. I have not looked close at the specs for a csv, but I don't think comma's are supported. In fact, I did not know that SQL server even supports a ", in a column name, and am rather surprised that SQL server or csv files allow as such.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal [SQL Server Column Name Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations?view=sql-server-ver16) yeah you really can name SQL Server columns with about any chars, as long as you use back quotes around it

Comment: Thanks - as noted, it did not "dawn" on me that "," in column name would and was allowed (learn something new everyday). Of course, I don't even allow spaces in my column names, but of course often it not me who created the database or software (so not the developer's call when such nonsense occurs). As noted I think I would alias the column name as [10000] and remove the "," our of the column name. It is also possible that that surrounding the column name with "10,000" would work. After all, csv files do support data with comma's if you surround the data with " (quotes).

Comment: Hi @NenadZivkovic - I am storing the data in datatable and then converting it to csv. Below is the code for that.

public static void ToCSV(this DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, true);
            //headers  
            for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write(dtDataTable.Columns[i]);
                if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Hi, please don't write code into comments, update your question with all relevant data that can help someone get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the function of **ToCSV(this DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)** into your question instead of in a comment.

The problem occurs because commas are commonly used as delimiters in CSV files. To handle this, you can enclose the column names in double quotes.

```
public static void ToCSV(this DataTable dtDataTable, string strFilePath)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);

    // Headers
    for (int i = 0; i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sw.Write("\"" + dtDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + "\"");
        if (i < dtDataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
}
```